# Setting OSX 10.12 Homepage with ARD

Tags: macos, terminal, safari

I have always been able to set my users Safari homepage with a simple command

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari HomePage http://www.MyDistrictSchoolPage.com
```

Now with Safari 10.0.1 in osx 10.12 this no longer works.  Ive looked and even deleted everything "Safari" inside the ~Library folder and that DOES reset safari in every respect EXCEPT the homepage.  This is driving me crazy.  Does anyone know a workaround for this?